# Error in converting caffe_xilinx model to onnx

Tags: onnx, vitis-ai

I am trying to convert a caffe_xilinx yolov3 model to onnx and this is the link from where I have installed caffe2onnx: https://pypi.org/project/caffe2onnx/

and this is the error

> google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2027:3 : Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "deephi_resize_param"

How to get through this?

Comment: Which Caffe version are you using? There is probably a mismatch.

Comment: I am using caffe-xilinx version